# Is it possible to use a cell value as a workbook/worksheet reference in an excel formula?

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say I have a worksheet called "References". The value of cell B2 of this worksheet is
`"C:\Documents\Workbook1.xlsx"`,
the path to a workbook.

On another sheet within the same workbook I want a formula which gets the value of cell A1 of worksheet `"Sheet 1"` of `Workbook1.xlsx`. Is it possible to have the formula look up the value of `'References'!B2` and use it as a reference.

i.e. I'd expect the formula would be something like

```
='['References'!B2]Sheet 1'!A1
```

I have tried using the `CELL()` formula but can't seem to get it to work in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is a variable reference I presume that your source workbook is likely to be closed.

Attached is a summary (and screenshot in case the link ever changes) from Daily Dose of Excel covering how to pull a variable reference from a closed workbook . See [INDIRECT and closed workbooks](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/12/01/indirect-and-closed-workbooks/)

Three options are provided:

1. Laurent Longre has developed the free add-in [MOREFUNC.XLL](http://longre.free.fr/English/) which includes the function INDIRECT.EXT
2. SQL.REQUEST
3. Harlan Grove’s [PULL](http://tinyurl.com/63xon) function:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the referenced workbook is open, you can use the [INDIRECT()](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213933) function.